# Append IQueryable with additional query parts

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I have the following:

```
IQueryable<Entity1, Entity2> query = //some query with joins
return query.Distinct().ToList();
```

This works fine. What I want to do is to extend the query by adding some additional parts to it, like this:

```
IQueryable<Entity1, Entity2> query = //some query with joins
return query.Distinct().ToList();

if (something)
{
     query = query.Concat(query.Where(some conditions here));
}
else
{
     query = query.Concat(query.Where(some other conditions));
}

return query.Distinct().ToList();
```

Unfortunately in that case `query` is null after `query.Concat`.

I have also tried:

```
var subquery = query.Concat(query.Where(some other conditions));
```

but it returns the same result. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you please explain why do you need `query.Concat(query.Where`? You are adding some elements to the same collection (creating a duplicates). But after this you do `Distinct`. I don't get this logic

Comment: You can't `Concat` a query to itself (well you can, but the results will be highly unintuitive). If you just want to add additional conditions, just add a `.Where`. If you want to use the same query as a basis for an actual union operation with different conditions, things get complicated, because there's no simple way to "clone" a query. You may need to restructure things so only the `Where` conditional is built differently and `query` is built but once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.Concat(...)` does a union all.  If all you want to do is add a predicate then just swap the current `query` with `query.Where(...)`

```
IQueryable<Entity1, Entity2> query = //some query with joins

if (something)
{
     query = query.Where(some conditions here);
}
else
{
     query = query.Where(some other conditions);
}
return query.Distinct().ToList();
```

... you can even use query syntax.

```
var query = from e in yourDbContext.YourTable 
            select e;

if (something) 
{
    query = from e in query
            where someCondition
            select e;
}
return query.Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I have tried it at first, but it didn't work. Turns out I had made a dumb mistake somewhere else in my code and once I fixed it, the simplest solution worked great. Concat was kind of an overkill for this, even more so that I didn't understand it correctly :)